# Python tkinter Entry widget displays bar characters instead of line breaks

Tags: python, user-interface, character-encoding, tkinter

I'm coding a very simple Python Tkinter GUI to drive a command-line python script.
My GUI will run on a Windows host and I want it to display the multi-line plain-text output of the script, which is returned to the GUI as a string containing - of course - line breaks (`\n` characters).

So, I put a Text widget into the GUI and when my script - in example - returns an output which starts with this substring:

    `RESULT STATUS: OK- Service is currently running\n\nDETAILS: ...`

the text displayed contains black vertical bars (`|`) whenever there is a `\n` line break character.

Lines are correctly broken but those strange bars make me think that the `\n` line break character is not correctly decoded, and I don't want the bars in my displayed output.

Any idea on how to make Tkinter display correctly line-endings? Thanks in advance.

### Code

This is the workflow for my GUI:

1. I click a button, which calls the callMe() callback function
2. The callMe() function parses the arguments coming from an Entry widget and then invokes the python command-line script
3. The script returns the above-mentioned string and this is used by the callback to update the text of the Text widget

Here is the code:

```
#init the GUI elements and the Text widget
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()     
top = Frame(root)
outputFrame = Frame(top)
outputFrame.pack(side='top', padx=20, pady=20)
outputTextArea = Text(outputFrame, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, width=150, height=40)
outputTextArea.pack(side='left', expand=YES, fill='both')

#callback executed when the button is clicked
def callMe()

    #get parameters
    # .....


    #command line execution script execution
    process = subprocess.Popen(command_line, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

    #get script output
    matr = process.stdout.readlines()  

    #from a list of strings to a single string
    output = "".join(matr)

    #write output into the Text widget
    outputTextArea.insert(0.0, output)
```

Comment: You say you put a Text widget into the GUI but the behavior you describe sounds like you're using and Entry widget. Are you certain you are using a text widget?

Answer (score 3):

It could be an issue of '\r' characters before each '\n' character (you said you're on Windows).

Before updating the widget, try first:

```
text_output= text_output.replace('\r', '')
```

(text_output contains the output of your script, whose contents are to be inserted in the widget)

If you give us more information, we can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

When to use the Entry Widget (from http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm)

The entry widget is used to enter text strings. This widget allows the user to enter one line of text, in a single font.

To enter multiple lines of text, use the Text widget.

Comment: As you suggested me, I switched frm Entry widget to Text widget (that's definitely the correct widget choice for text displaying). Unfortunately, I'm still having those annoying bars diplayed!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it's impossible to say for certain what the problem is. You say you use a text widget but the behavior seems consistent with using an entry widget. Do you still see the vertical bars with the following code?

```
import Tkinter as tk

OUTPUT = "RESULT STATUS: OK- Service is currently running\n\nDETAILS: ... "

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root, height=4, width=80)
text.pack(fill="both", expand="true")
text.insert("end", OUTPUT)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question thanks to ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ..it was a matter of `/r` characters..I guess that when I invoke the subprocess.Popen to run my command-line script, a Windows Command Prompt is open, the script executed, and the standard output stream is returned by the Prompt with `/r/n` line-endings instead of just `/n`.

Anyway, I will post the code and GUI workflow all the way...

### Workflow

This is the workflow for my GUI:

1. I click a button, which calls the callMe() callback function
2. The callMe() function parses the arguments coming from an Entry widget and then invokes the python command-line script
3. The script returns the above-mentioned string and this is used by the callback to update the text of the Text widget

### Code

Here is the code:

```
#init the GUI elements and the Text widget
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()     
top = Frame(root)
outputFrame = Frame(top)
outputFrame.pack(side='top', padx=20, pady=20)
outputTextArea = Text(outputFrame, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, width=150, height=40)
outputTextArea.pack(side='left', expand=YES, fill='both')

#callback executed when the button is clicked
def callMe():

    #get parameters
    # .....

    #command line execution script execution
    process = subprocess.Popen(command_line, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

    #get script output
    matr = process.stdout.readlines()  

    #from a list of strings to a single string
    output = "".join(matr)  # <<< now it is:  output = "".join(matr).replace('\r', '')

    #write output into the Text widget
    outputTextArea.insert(0.0, output)
```

Thanks very much to all of you, guys!